# poetry: no way exclude dependencies for production?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I’m publishing a Python package.

It has dependencies a, b, c. It also has pytest as a dependency, defined in the `group.dev` as per poetry’s documentation.

However, I couldn’t find a conclusive answer for the following question:

When some installs my library with:

```
pip install my_library
```

Is `pytest` (defined in any group other than the main group, in this case `dev`) also installed? That would be very undesirable.

Comment: Dev dependencies don't get installed when you do a normal `poetry install`. Do you have some reason to think it would be different for `pip`?

Comment: @mblakesley No specific reason. But no “official” confirmation for what you’re describing either. I guess I could test this quite easily, but I was hoping for more explicit information on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mention the dev dependency like this. It will not install the `pytest`. [Reference](https://realpython.com/dependency-management-python-poetry/)

```
# rp_poetry/pyproject.toml (Excerpt)

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
requests = "^2.26.0"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.2"
black = "^21.9b0"
```

*poetry is may go to change the label of `dev-dependencies` in the future.*

Comment: side-note: poetry is going to deprecate `dev-dependencies` soon. I’ve read that article, it would be nice to quote the relevant section.

Comment: To clarify `zerohedge`'s statement, they're not removing the functionality of dev dependencies, they're merely changing the label for dev dependencies.

Comment: @mblakesley yes. I should’ve clarified that.

Comment: Though dev-dependencies is still supported as a legacy syntax, here is the new way of writing it:
`[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]`
from https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-dependencies/